# Regular Exression to extract strings within multiple different delimitiers

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to extract strings between multiple delimiters in a c# app. Example below:

```
#K06[1234567-0257;S2W546#20-H2]
```

required output :

```
0257S2W54620
```

I need to extract what's between the first `-` and `;`, append what's between the `;` and `#` and finally append the string between `#` and the final `-`.

I'd like to achieve this using regular expressions and as the string could change in the future.

I'm struggling to append the 3 substrings in a single RegEx.

Comment: Even a simple `-(.*);(.*)#(.*)-` could have done the trick for simple string like this. You should read a bit about regex, there is a ton of ressource online. And even site like [RegexOne](https://regexone.com/) that can drive you into understanding basic regex in few step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regex that will do what you want is:

```
-([^;]+);([^#]+)#([^-]+)
```

You can then concatenate group 1,2 and 3.

Play with it at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/YAwfhH/1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Works great!

Answer (score 2):

If your input arent going to change and you are willing to not use a regex, you can use this one liner:

```
var y = x.Split('-')[1].Replace(";", "").Replace("#", "");
```

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0QvxoT)

- We use `Split()` to trim code before and after.
- We use `Replace()` to remove noise.

fullcode:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var x = "#K06[1234567-0257;S2W546#20-H2]"; 

        var y = x.Split('-')[1].Replace(";", "").Replace("#", "");
        Console.WriteLine(y == "0257S2W54620");
        Console.WriteLine(y);
    }
}
```